# Inactive prospects in a drip program in pardot

Tags: automation, pardot

A drip program in Pardot running based on a dynamic list. Currently there are 10 prospects in the program coming through that list. All these prospects are either 'Never Active' or 'Inactive since March 2019'. will they pass through to next step (sending email)?

Here is what the drip program says:

```
Entry point - dynamic list. Next step, wait for 6 days and send the email - end.
```

(I paused the program once in between, I hope it will not start the 6 days waiting period from the beginning.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes prospects that enter the program will follow all the steps, regardless if they are active or not.

Pausing the program will also pause the waiting time, it should not restart counting.
*(At least not unless you change the number of days of that step... but I have yet to confirm this.)*

Comment: Thanks Philippe.

Comment: The only thing that will prevent the email from being sent is if the contact has opt-out  or if its email has bounced (DoNotEmail or Opted Out fields).